# Deserialize Builder Class without using Jacksonized

Tags: jackson, lombok

I can successfully deserialize my builder class using [@Jacksonized](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized)

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Jacksonized
public class Person {
    Private String firstName;  
    Private String lastName; 
    @JsonDeserialize(contentAs=AgeClassImpl1.class) 
    Private AgeClass age;  // AgeClass interface has 2 implementations but I always to use impl1

    Public static Person create(final String fN, final String lN, final AgeClass age) {
        PersonBuilder builder = PersonBuilder.builder()
                                .firstName(fN)
                                .lastName(lN)
                                .age(age);
        builder.build()
    }
}
```

However, I need to get rid of `@Jacksonized`. To achieve the same effect as `@Jacksonized`, I manually added the annotations as shown below:

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize(builder=Person.PersonBuilder.class)
public class Person {
    Private String firstName;  
    Private String lastName; 
    @JsonDeserialize(contentAs=AgeClassImpl1.class) 
    Private AgeClass age;  // AgeClass interface has 2 implementations but I always to use impl1


    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="")
    public static class PersonBuilder {}

    Public static Person create(final String fN, final String lN, final AgeClass age) {
        PersonBuilder builder = PersonBuilder.builder()
                                .firstName(fN)
                                .lastName(lN)
                                .age(age);
        builder.build()
    }
}
```

Getting error:

> InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `AgeClass` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding @NoArgsConstructor or also known as default/empty constructor in your AgeClass.
As to deserialize, empty constructor is used. You have used it in Person class, but check once in AgeClass

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).